# Flexbox - Center two items that are on different row

Tags: css, html, flexbox

I'm trying to learn Flexbox and I've encountered the first problem.
Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:
I've an header and I would like to have the logo on the first row at the center, then the burger menu always at the center but on the second row, so below the logo.

With my code the burger menu will place itself next to the logo on the same row.

Here's my code:

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

body{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

.wrapper{
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 1500px;
 position: relative;
 margin: auto;
}
.flex-container-header{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 margin-top: 50px;
}
#flex-logo{
 width: 30%;
 height: 30%;
 
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 
 
 <meta author="Example">
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Example</title>
 <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 
</head>
<body>
 
 <div class="wrapper">
 <div id="header">
    <nav> 
   <div class="flex-container-header">
    <img src="img/logo.png" id="flex-logo" alt="Logo">
    <img src="img/burger-menu.png" id="burger-menu" alt="Burger Menu">
   </div> 
   
  </nav>
 </div>
 </div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _“With my code the burger menu will place itself next to the logo on the same row.”_ - it has no reason to wrap on to a second line, because there is enough space for both elements on the same line. You either need to make the items wider, or change the flex-direction.

Answer (score 2):

To align the elements vertically you must use `flex-direction: column` and `flex-wrap: wrap` is not necessary. Here is an example:

```css
.wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1500px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.flex-container-header{
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 50px;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="header">
    <nav> 
      <div class="flex-container-header">
        <img src="img/logo.png" id="flex-logo" alt="Logo">
        <img src="img/burger-menu.png" id="burger-menu" alt="Burger Menu">
      </div> 
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: justify-content: center; is not necessary